# Middle click in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: mouse, windows-11, microsoft-edge

I'm used to using the middle mouse button in browsers to open links in a new tab. However, Microsoft Edge has added an "additional capability": drag the browsing window up and down. However, it seems to think I want to move the window up and down when I really want to open a link in a new tab.

How can I disable middle click to drag behaviour in Edge (Windows 11)?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will map middle-click to ctrl-click in Edge:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe msedge.exe
MButton::Send, ^{LButton}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)